# Why am I unable to save JavaScript in a Content Editor Web Part?

Tags: javascript, content-editor-web-part

I am trying to follow [this link](http://geekswithblogs.net/shehan/archive/2010/03/02/jquery-slideshow.aspx) and put all the code in a CEWP as suggested. After saving the page the code goes away (except for the gear part, top line).

I could really use some help if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sorry if I'm stating the obvious here... but you are clicking the Source Editor button and not the Rich Text Editor button when editing the Web part aren't you?

For SP2010, see: http://sptwentyten.wordpress.com/2010/08/31/insert-javascript-into-a-content-editor-web-part-cewp

Comment: @Nigel: html source editor button

Comment: @Julie It didn't click with me that you are using SP2010. I found this link that should help: http://sptwentyten.wordpress.com/2010/08/31/insert-javascript-into-a-content-editor-web-part-cewp

Comment: @Nigel: Thanks for sharing the link. I think the js is not resolving b/c the page or the cewp is blank. I dont even see any exclamation sign on the status bar. Is not even getting loaded b/c i turn on the developer tool from ie and those references r completely missing from the page.

Comment: @Julie Are you trying to reference the file using a <script> tag within the Content Editor Web part or are you specifying the file as a content link as the article describes?

Comment: @Nigel: Actually, cewp is all blank. everything is in the text file. I clean the browser cache and now i can see the error through developer tool. its on <GetListItems , i didnot noticed any syntax error.

Comment: @Nigel: It's finally working. Thanks Nigel. It had extra space after getlistitems. Thanks

Comment: @Julie Glad you got it sorted.  :)

Answer (score 2):

There is probably an error in the code which the CEWP is unable to save. You could save the JavaScript functions in another file and reference that file instead of placing all the code in the web part. You'll still need to debug it, but at least you'll be able to save the web part with just the script references and the call to the function.

Another option is to eliminate the CEWP and instead edit the Page Layout file in SharePoint Designer and insert your code there.

Comment: I saved the js in a file and made a reference in the cewp. I then reran or F5 the page. Nothing happened. so cranked one ie developer tool and noticed that those js files are not in the page.

Answer (score 1):

The safest and easiest way to do this is to not save the code directly in the web part. The CEWP is trying to be clever and strips  tags out because it sees it as potentially dangerous. 
Rather do this:

- Using SharePoint Designer, browse to Site Assests.
- Create a new HTM File (Call it what you want)
- Stick your code etc in there and save it
- Go back to your page and use a CEWP.
- Add the Url (Relative) to your htm file in the Content Link section like so:

[image]

Save and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the CEWP try it with the Simple Form WebPart instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I finally figured out what was happening. The problem occurred in pages that were created by the Sys Admin, not by me. If I created the page the Javascript code would not be stripped. Try that.